I messed up Gnome and KDE
I am running ubuntu 20.04
I installed kubuntu-desktop using apt
Kde launched but I got a torrent of error messages.
So I decided to remove kubuntu-desktop using apt remove and apt purge
The error messages went away but the weird thing was I could still log in to kde
I decided to be safe and try to do a clean remove and I did something stupid and removed some remaining plasma packages using synaptic package manager
Now I can't get any window manager in Ubuntu, just a crash screen
The error message says:
Oh no! Something has gone wrong.
A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please contact a system administrator.
Any way to fix the window manager from a live disk?

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.

Have you tried just logging into a text terminal, and sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop ??   For specific help on your issue we'd need to likely know what exactly you removed & thus what needs to be installed; but that would require details you've not provided (but would be found in your apt logs if you looked)

I was able to boot into grub by holding down Esc at just the right time during boot. The reason why I didn't do this first was because the timing was precise and I missed it
From grub I was able to load an older ZFS savestate
